# How to inject IConfiguration in .NET Core 3.x

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I ran into an issue with using `IConfiguration` to obtain secrets from a key vault in .NET Core 3.x. Say I have a class which needs `IConfiguration`:

```
public class NeedsConfiguration : INeedsConfiguration
{
    private readonly config;

    public NeedsConfiration(IConfiguraion config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    // What it does with config is less important...
}
```

This works out of the box, for some properties, like environment variables (and I think also appsettings). But when it comes to secrets, even if you have called `services.AddAzureKeyVault("key-vault-url")`, you cannot see the secrets on `config` inside the class.

For that to work, I have found two ways, which works.

1. Add the `Configuration` property from `Startup.cs` as a singleton, with `services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);`.
2. Do some manual work when adding classes which needs `IConfiguration`, so the above class would be added with `services.AddScoped<INeedsConfiguration>(x => new NeedsConfiguration(Configuration));`

The latter of the two, seems like a lot of manual labor. The first seems better, but if this is the intended way, why isn't it a part of the template to begin with?

Can anyone tell me, how you are intended to set up `IConfiguration` injection in .NET Core 3.x?

And as a bonus question, why does it partially work (e.g. I can see env. variables, but not secrets)?

Comment: I use your first method without issue. Only the designers of the framework can speak to why it's not automatically included in DI, but my guess that they want to limit what gets included automatically due to performance, memory, security, etc. Not all use-cases would require making IConfiguration available in DI, so my devil's advocate argument is that it shouldn't automatically be included.

Comment: @Luke it just seemed so obvious, that I was afraid I was walking into a trap. It is comforting to hear, that someone else has done it successfully. And also, that my ideas aren't way off target. Thanks :)

Comment: According to the ASP.NET Core [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1)  it should work out of the box.

Comment: Why ask for `IConfiguration`?  I haven't ever used `AddAzureKeyVault()` but I imagine the results inside the configuration can be extracted the standard way, i. e. `IOptions<ClassThatMapsToTheVaultsData>`.  Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @GuruStron isn't that for .NET 6? There are some small differences in .NET Core 3.x.

Comment: @JoséRamírez you might be able to use the options pattern, but for this particular case I only had a single connection string, which made it seem reasonable to use IConfiguration directly.

Comment: I once added it successfully with `builder.AddAzureKeyVault(...)` in a .NET Core 3.1 web api.